# Regexp matching hashtags not wrapped in html tags

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I want to make regexp match of hashtags started by @ or #, and not wrapped in html anchor tag.
My expression: `(@|#)([a-zA-Z_]+)(?!<\/[a])` doesn't work, because in text:

```
<p>@john Olor it amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
Aenean commodofadgfsd 
<a class="autocompletedTag" href="#" data-id="u:2">@john_wayne</a></p>
```

Matches `@john` and `@john_wayne`, but I don't want to match `@john_wayne`.

How can Ido this?

**Examples**

In code :

```
<p>@john @kate <a>@royal_baby</a> #england <a>#russia</a></p>
```

I want to match `@john`, `@kate` and `#england`, but **not** `@royal_baby` and `#russia`.

In this code:

```
<p>#sale #stack #hello <a>@batman</a> #avengers <a>#iron_man</a></p>
```

I want to match `#sale`, `#stack`, `#hello` and `#avengers`, but **not** `@batman` and `#iron_man`.

Comment: But `@john` is wrapped in the `<p>` tag?

Comment: Yes, it is. I want to get rid of hashtags wrapped by <a class="autocompletedTag"></a>

Comment: No, I want to only not match this hashtag. I want only match tags unwrapped by `<a ...>@tag</a>`

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is relevant.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Why you think I can't do regexp match on piece of html, when I want only to get piece of text unwrapped by one tag?

Comment: I just re-read your question about 3 or 4 times, and I'm completely confused about what you want. Give us a couple of examples of what you DO want to match, and a couple of examples of what you DON'T want to match. Right now, I have no idea.

Comment: Although slightly contrived, `<p><![CDATA[ <a>@john</a> ]]></p>` is valid xhtml for an @ tag not wrapped in an <a> tag`. As per the link, (X)HTML is not parsable properly by regular expressions.

Comment: @TomLord I've updated question, examples added.

Comment: What about `<a><i>#mytag</i></a>`? How structured is your input? If it's just tag soup, how do you treat items like `<b>@mytag</a>` that is invalid HTML but would break any number of attempts to parse via regular expressions. I guess my point is that if you want to parse HTML, use an HTML parser.

Comment: I'm writing plugin for TinyMCE editor - hashtag autocompleter. I know there is another, working plugin, but it don't suits to my all needs, and I have to write my own.
So all #hashtags I want to match from content are inputed by user, so they aren't wrapped by any tag like <b> or <i>. When I match unwrapped hashtags, I want to show autocomplete window, to let user choose hashtag from list, and after that I wrap this tag to <a>. But when someone edit document, I don't want to match tags which are already wrapped in previous edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
/(<a[^>]*>.*?[@#][a-zA-Z_]+.*?<\/a>)|([@#][a-zA-Z_]+)/g
```

The idea is to match *both* cases and use a callback to filter them:

```
input = '<p>@john Olor it amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.\
Aenean commodofadgfsd \
<a class="autocompletedTag" href="#" data-id="u:2">@john_wayne</a></p>\
<p>@john @kate <a>@royal_baby</a> #england <a>#russia</a></p>\
<p>#sale #stack #hello <a>@batman</a> #avengers <a>#iron_man</a></p>';

matches = new Array(); //empty array
input.replace(/(<a[^>]*>.*?[@#][a-zA-Z_]+.*?<\/a>)|([@#][a-zA-Z_]+)/g, function(all, a, result){
    if(result){ // If the second group exists
        matches.push(result); // then add it to matches
    }
});

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = matches.join(); // Store results
```

[**Online jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6M7tf/)

**Explanation**

- `[@#]` : match either `@` or `#` one time
- `[a-zA-Z_]+` : match letters and underscore one or more times
- `<a` : match `<a`
- `[^>]*>` : match anything except `>` zero or more times and match `>` at the end
- `.*?[@#][a-zA-Z_]+.*?` : match what's between `<a></a>` ungreedy
- `<\/a>` : match the closing tag `</a>`